# Remove columns with all values missing in dataframe Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, missing-data

I have the following dataframe called df:

```
df = DataFrame(i=1:5,
               x=[missing, missing, missing, missing, missing],
               y=[missing, missing, 1, 3, 6])
5×3 DataFrame
 Row │ i      x        y       
     │ Int64  Missing  Int64?  
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1  missing  missing 
   2 │     2  missing  missing 
   3 │     3  missing        1
   4 │     4  missing        3
   5 │     5  missing        6
```

I would like to remove the columns where all values are missing. In this case it should remove column x because it has only all `missing` values. with `dropmissing` it removes all rows, but that's not what I want. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to remove only columns where all values are missing in a dataframe Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A mediocre answer would be:

```
df1 = DataFrame()
foreach(
  x->all(ismissing, df[!, x]) ? nothing : df1[!, x] = df[!, x],
  propertynames(df)
)

df
# 5×2 DataFrame
#  Row │ i      y
#      │ Int64  Int64?
# ─────┼────────────────
#    1 │     1  missing
#    2 │     2  missing
#    3 │     3        1
#    4 │     4        3
#    5 │     5        6
```

2. But a slightly better one would be using the slicing approach:

```
df[:, map(x->!all(ismissing, df[!, x]), propertynames(df))]
# 5×2 DataFrame
#  Row │ i      y
#      │ Int64  Int64?
# ─────┼────────────────
#    1 │     1  missing
#    2 │     2  missing
#    3 │     3        1
#    4 │     4        3
#    5 │     5        6

# OR
df[!, map(x->!all(ismissing, x), eachcol(df))]
# 5×2 DataFrame
#  Row │ i      y
#      │ Int64  Int64?
# ─────┼────────────────
#    1 │     1  missing
#    2 │     2  missing
#    3 │     3        1
#    4 │     4        3
#    5 │     5        6

#Or
df[!, Not(names(df, all.(ismissing, eachcol(df))))]
# I omitted the result to prevent this answer from becoming extensively lengthy.

#Or
df[!, Not(all.(ismissing, eachcol(df)))]
```

3. I almost forgot the `deleteat!` function:

```
deleteat!(permutedims(df), all.(ismissing, eachcol(df))) |> permutedims

# 5×2 DataFrame
#  Row │ i      y
#      │ Int64  Int64?
# ─────┼────────────────
#    1 │     1  missing
#    2 │     2  missing
#    3 │     3        1
#    4 │     4        3
#    5 │     5        6
```

4. You can use the `select!` function, as [Dan noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74874476/remove-columns-with-all-values-missing-in-dataframe-julia#comment132137579_74874696):

```
select!(df, [k for (k,v) in pairs(eachcol(df)) if !all(ismissing, v)])
# 5×2 DataFrame
#  Row │ i      y
#      │ Int64  Int64?
# ─────┼────────────────
#    1 │     1  missing
#    2 │     2  missing
#    3 │     3        1
#    4 │     4        3
#    5 │     5        6
```

Comment: `select!(df, [k for (k,v) in pairs(eachcol(df)) if !all(ismissing, v)])` looks nice also.

Comment: @DanGetz Yes, of course!

Answer (score 1):

The `names` functions accepts a type as an input to select columns of a specific type, so I would do:

```
julia> select(df, Not(names(df, Missing)))
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ i      y       
     │ Int64  Int64?  
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1  missing 
   2 │     2  missing 
   3 │     3        1
   4 │     4        3
   5 │     5        6
```

Without benchmarking this I would guess that it is also significantly faster, as it doesn't have to check each element of each column but as far as I know simply queries the type information for each column readily available in the DataFrame:

```
julia> dump(df)
DataFrame
  columns: Array{AbstractVector}((3,))
    1: Array{Int64}((5,)) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    2: Array{Missing}((5,))
      1: Missing missing
      2: Missing missing
      3: Missing missing
      4: Missing missing
      5: Missing missing
    3: Array{Union{Missing, Int64}}((5,))
```

The downside of this approach is that it relies on the type information to be correct, which might not be the case after a transformation:

```
julia> df2 = df[1:2, :]
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ i      x        y       
     │ Int64  Missing  Int64?  
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1  missing  missing 
   2 │     2  missing  missing
```

This can be fixed by calling `identity` to narrow column types, but this is again potentially expensive:

```
julia> identity.(df2)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ i      x        y       
     │ Int64  Missing  Missing 
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │     1  missing  missing 
   2 │     2  missing  missing
```

So I'd say if you're creating a DataFrame from scratch, such as reading it in via XLSX.jl (as people loooove putting empty columns in their Excel sheet) or are creating whole columns in your workflow, `names(df, Not(Missing))` is the way to go, while for analysis on subsets of DataFrames it's only guaranteed to work when using `identity` so that the other approaches mentioned which check every cell are viable alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple option is to use

```
df[!, any.(!ismissing, eachcol(df))]
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ i      y
     │ Int64  Int64?
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1  missing
   2 │     2  missing
   3 │     3        1
   4 │     4        3
   5 │     5        6
```

and if the DataFrame is created from scratch, there is another fast option using the column type. Since any column with all missing entries `isa Vector{Missing}`, we can use this `Type` information to skip these columns. The drawback of this fast method as @NilsGudat pointed out, is that it fails if the DataFrame column types have changed by some transformation.

```
df[!, (!isa).(eachcol(df), Vector{Missing})]
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ i      y
     │ Int64  Int64?
─────┼────────────────
   1 │     1  missing
   2 │     2  missing
   3 │     3        1
   4 │     4        3
   5 │     5        6
```